# issues with git rebase -i HEAD~2

Tags: git, gitlab

here is my git log:

```
$ git log --oneline
0729a5e (HEAD -> feature/fork_deploy_function) merge with gitlab
0a6421d implement aws kubernetes deploy phase1
bde4da0 (origin/feature/fork_deploy_function) partially implement kubenetes deployment
```

`bde4da0` is the latest one in gitlab, and I made a local commit `0a6421d`, and a pull and merge branch commit `0729a5e`. Now before I push my local commit to gitlab I'd like to squash the last two commits `0729a5e` and `0a6421d` to one commit by using `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, supprisingly, when I run it I get commits `bde4da0` and `0a6421d` in the editor instead of `0729a5e` and `0a6421d`. see below:

```
pick 0a6421d implement aws kubernetes deploy phase1
pick bde4da0 partially implement kubenetes deployment
```

how come this happen? and how can I squash the first two commits in this case? Thanks

Comment: You said `0729a5e` is a merge ("and a pull and merge branch commit..."). Rebase normally discards merges. Use `git log --graph` (perhaps also with `--oneline`), or some other graph-viewing tool, to visualize the graph before rebasing. A linear display like this is not going to help much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but this should not fail:

```
git checkout 0729a5e
git reset --soft bde4da0
# all changes introduced by the last two revisions will be in index, ready to be committed
git commit -m "squash"
# if you like the result
git branch -f feature/fork_deploy_function
```